# htaccess - Remove trailing forward slash except for

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in htaccess to remove trailing slashes:

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.example\.com$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This works great, but I now need to add an exception to that rule.
I have a folder (lets call it 'myfolder') that needs a trailing slash.  Is it possible to ammend the above condition to allow this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, like this, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myfolder/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will exclude `http://example.com/myfolder/` from being redirected to `http://example.com/myfolder`. If `myfolder` is located in a subfolder then you need to alter the path in rewrite condition accordingly.

---

If you want to exclude `myfolder` regardless of where it is located (e.g. `/myfolder/`, `/something/myfolder/` or `/something/interesting/myfolder/`) then alter rewrite condition accordingly:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/myfolder/$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks once again, LazyOne :)